# Can I play Fable: The Journey without the Kinect?

Tags: xbox-360, kinect, fable-the-journey

The question in the title says it all... Can I play Fable: The Journey without the Kinect?  I have done some searching for it, but could not find any creditable sources.  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinect is **required** for Fable: The Journey.

This info is on the [Xbox.com page for the game](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Fable-The-Journey/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8024d530a1a) - look just to the right of the ESRB rating.

[Major Nelson's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Hryb) blog entry [for the demo](http://majornelson.com/2012/09/17/demo-fable-the-journey/) also notes that you'll need the Kinect sensor to play.

Contrast this with the page for [Mass Effect 3](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Mass-Effect-3/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8024541095d) which has the official branding for "Better with the Kinect Sensor" (just underneath the tabs at the top of the page, in white text on purple).

Comment: aww durrrrr! Thank you for pointing that out.  (didn't see that prior to when looking there) I almost want to vote this a close.

Comment: Thanks for the edit as well, that clears that up for me.

Comment: @Foxtrot, eh, no biggie :)  Kinect-required games also seem to always come in purple cases, as opposed to the green of a normal Xbox 360 game.  I'm pretty sure that's intentional, to distinguish them.